I am using vue 3 to connect to supabase database and pull records into a table. I am having some trouble deleting a row using a click event
I am new to vue 3 and I am following some online vue 3 training:)
so I get records back from the supabase database, the table the table gets populated with the exepected data. The last column has an action button with a delete button for every row. The challenge I am having is that When I click the delete button record nothing gets deleted. I tried few suggestions online but no luck.
Here is my template and the script:


<template>
    <a-table :data-source="posts">
    <a-table-column-group >
      <a-table-column key="name" data-index="fullName">
        <template #title><span style="color: #1890ff">Name</span></template>
      </a-table-column>
      <a-table-column key="amount" title="Amount" data-index="amount" />
      <a-table-column key="recieved_date" title="recieved_date" data-index="recieved_date" />
       <a-table-column key="description" title="Description" data-index="description" /> 
    <a-table-column key="id" title="ID" data-index="id" /> 
    <a-table-column key="action" title="Action">
        <span>      
         <AButton @click="deleteRow(row.id)">Delete</AButton> 
          </span>
         </a-table-column>
   </a-table-column-group>
  </a-table>
</template>
<script setup>
const columns = [{
  name: 'Name',
  dataIndex: 'fullName',
  key: 'fullName',
}, {
  title: 'recieved_date',
  dataIndex: 'recieved_date',
  key: 'recieved_date',
},  {
  title: 'Amount',
  key: 'amount',
  dataIndex: 'amount',
}, 
{
  title: 'Description',
  dataIndex: 'description',
  key: 'description',
},
{
  title: 'id',
  dataIndex: 'id',
  key: 'id',
 
 },
{
  title: 'Action',
  dataIndex: 'action',
  key: 'action',
 
 },
];

  //delete record
    
     const deleteRow = async () => {
    
    const { data,index } =
    await supabase.from("Contractor_Payment")
    .delete()
    .eq("id",row.id)
     
  onMounted(() => {
    fetchData()
  })
</script>




Does it get deleted from the database?  It looks like your delete function only sends a request to the backend. It is still necessary that you update the frontend data used by <a-table> to match the backend.  I am not that familiar with supabase but perhaps the data variable returned by the supabase request contains the updated information you need, otherwise you can always manually slice the deleted row from the dataset (I think posts in your case), or send a new GET request for the table data.

Thanks for the respond yoduh! It does not get deleted from the database. Yes, i am trying console.log the "data" and try to see what is being sent to the database for deletion if any.

"It does not get deleted from the database", you will need to solve this problem first then.  first check that the request is being sent using your browser's network dev tool.  provided the request is correctly sent, the problem will need to be investigated on the backend side.  possibly you're also receiving error response that could provide clues

I finally got this to work. There were couple of issues, the main issue was not having the appropriate supabase "delete" policy in place, also changed the table template to make it simple.
Here is the updated working template and script:


const deleteRow = async (id) => {
    const { data, error } = await supabase
      .from('Contractor_Payment')
      .delete()
      .eq("id", id);

    if (error) {
      console.error('Error deleting row:', error)
    } else {
      console.log('Row deleted:', id)
      // Optionally, update your UI to reflect the deletion
    }
  }
   
  onMounted(() => {
    fetchData()
  })

</script>
  
 <!-- Bind the data to the data-source attribute -->
 <template>
  <showModel />
  <modalTest />
     <div>
      <table>
        <tr v-for="row in posts" :key="row.id">
          <td>{{ row.fullName }}</td>
          <td>{{ row.amount }}</td>
          <td>{{ row.id }}</td>
          <td><button @click="deleteRow(row.id)">Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </template>





Instide you template pass a value row
<a-button @click="deleteRow(row)">Delete</a-button>


Then check what you have in console.log inside deleteRow method

Find item id

It maybe looks like this
<a-button @click="deleteRow(row.record.id)">Delete</a-button>


Then you need to get id from deleteRow argument
const deleteRow = async (id) => {
  console.log(id) // check you get id
  const { data, error } = await supabase
    .from("Contractor_Payment")
    .delete()
    .eq("id", id);

  if (!error) {
    fetchData();
  } 
};




Thank for looking this over! I appreciate it. I already tried that, I am getting "undefined" for the ID. clearly not passing the right input value to the method. if I hardcode the ID value into the method, the record that matches the ID will get removed. So i have to figure out on how to pass the right value from the input to the method.
